# Why is this Date string failing the validation?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetimeformatter, offsetdatetime

I have a JSON file with a value of **2020-03-07T04:11:20.000** for a field with given pattern
**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS**. I tried to add a Z at the end of it, but it keeps failing the validation.
Any idea why?

I tried to do
**OffsetDateTime.parse(mytext, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(mypattern))**
and it threw DateTimeParseException with Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor

Comment: What is the exception being thrown, if any? Show the code that is producing this.

Comment: A date-time field? LocalDateTime? (Not LocalDate)

Comment: Well, what does the validation do?

Comment: What code are you using to validate?

Comment: I tried to do OffsetDateTime.parse(mytext, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(mypattern)) and it threw DateTimeParseException with Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor

Comment: The field in the json has type OffsetDateTime and is annotated with that pattern.

Comment: There is no offset in the `String`, you will have to add one when parsing...

Comment: What do you mean by offset? Could you please give me an example of amended string?

Comment: I mean something inside the `String` that tells how many hours the value differs from UTC. For example: `2020-03-07T04:11:20.000+01:00`

Comment: The JSON annotation is @JsonFormat(shape=Shape.String, pattern = my pattern, timezone="UTC").

Comment: @user998692 Thank you for providing a wealth of good information in response comments. It’s even better to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63505330/edit) the question and add all the information there so we have everything in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since neither the pattern nor the input has a timezone offset, you can't parse it directly to `OffsetDateTime`. What you can do is parse the date as `LocalDateTime` and add the offset to the result.

For example, using ZoneOffset.UTC:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(mytext, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(mypattern));
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are using the wrong class, `OffsetDateTime` for your case. Since you have mentioned `timezone="UTC"`, you should use `ZonedDateTime`. Note that after using the following annotation, the date-time produced will be like `2020-03-07T04:11:20.000 UTC`.

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS z", timezone="UTC")
```

which you can parse into `ZonedDateTime` using the pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS z`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS z";
        String myText = "2020-03-07T04:11:20.000 UTC";
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(myText, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(myPattern)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-03-07T04:11:20Z[UTC]
```

If you want to keep the date-time format as `2020-03-07T04:11:20.000` then you should remove `timezone="UTC"` from the annotation and parse the obtained date-time string into a `LocalDateTime` instead of `ZonedDateTime`. Needless to say that the pattern should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` in that case.